# Adding a plain text fallback with HTML email

Tags: html, email, mime, plaintext

I've already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790615/sending-html-newsletters-with-plain-text-fallback) but it doesn't seem to be the method I need.

What I'm doing at the moment is creating an email as a .html file then attaching it in Outlook and sending - What I want to do is send an email over Outlook that has HTML/CSS styling but also has a plain text version as a fallback.

I've been searching and searching and all i'm getting is info about MIME (Multi-Purpose Internet Mail Extensions) and that's about as far as I got :/

Is there something I can simply add to the code of my html file that determines whether to use HTML or plain text?

Comment: You have to use MIME to specify that you are sending a multi-part email. You can't do that from within the document. How you do it depends on the software you are using to send the email. Outlook doesn't give you any control over this as far as I know, but is end user application software anyway so questions about it should be directed to SuperUser and not Stackoverflow.

Comment: "I've already seen this post but it doesn't seem to be the method I need." — It **is** the method you need.

Answer (score 9):

You need have a multi part email with 2 parts.  The first is a text/plain and the second is the text/html.  The first part has the body be the email with no formatting.  It needs to be first because the parts are suppose to go from worst to best.

Answer (score -1):

It's not HTML text that needs to be changed, but it's headers sent along email.

I don't know how are you sending email from HTML, but all you have to do is to set header to `Content-Type: text/plain;"` instead of `Content-Type: text/html;"`. Then your email content will be sent as plain text without any parsing.

[Maybe relevant search](https://www.google.lt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=change%20outlook%20headers)

Comment: No. The question is asking how to send an HTML formatted mail with a plain text fallback, not a plain text mail.

Comment: @Quentin Did you find a solution?