# Send HTML mail with fallback to plain text mail via Swiftmailer

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

How can you send HTML mail with a fallback to plain text mail with PHP Swiftmailer?

Answer (score 2):

Create a message in Swiftmailer and use the `setBody()` function to set the text/plain version of your mail and use the `addPart()` function to set the text/html version of your email (with second parameter `text/html`):

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setSubject('Your subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ->addPart('<p>Here is the message itself</p>', 'text/html')
  ;
```

Checkout the source: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html